# wish to use empID from `users` table to `leave` table

Tags: mysql

i am relatively new in phpmysql.i need some help...

i have two table namely `users` and `leave`.In `users` table i have following column

1. empID(int)
2. username(varchar)
3. password(varchar)
4. mac(varchar)
5. ip(varchar)

and in `leave` table i have following column

1. lid(int)
2. empname(varchar)
3. username(varchar)
4. nod(int)
5. sdate(date)
6. edate(date)
7. reason(varchar)
8. action(varchar)

Now i want to use `empID` in `leave` table.how can i use it.i have to say that i already apply a  code but its not working.Its giving the following error..

## 1072 - Key column 'empID' doesn't exist in table

and the code

```
create table `leave`(
lid INT NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
empname VARCHAR(255) NOT NULL,
username VARCHAR(255) NOT NULL,
nod INT NOT NULL,
sdate DATE,
edate DATE,
reason VARCHAR(255) NOT NULL,
PRIMARY KEY(lid),
FOREIGN KEY(empID) REFERENCES users(empID)
);
```

so whats wrong...please help me..

Comment: I don't see `empID` column in table `leave`.

Answer (score 2):

```
create table `leave`(
lid INT NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
empname VARCHAR(255) NOT NULL,
username VARCHAR(255) NOT NULL,
nod INT NOT NULL,
sdate DATE,
edate DATE,
reason VARCHAR(255) NOT NULL,
PRIMARY KEY(lid),
FOREIGN KEY(empID) REFERENCES users(empID)
);
```

should be

```
create table `leave`(
lid INT NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
empID int, // here you need one like this
empname VARCHAR(255) NOT NULL,
username VARCHAR(255) NOT NULL,
nod INT NOT NULL,
sdate DATE,
edate DATE,
reason VARCHAR(255) NOT NULL,
PRIMARY KEY(lid),
FOREIGN KEY(empID) REFERENCES users(empID)
);
```

you are missing a `empID` column.

Answer (score 1):

Your SQL to create the *leave* table includes the correct bit to create the foreign key relationship:

```
FOREIGN KEY(empID) REFERENCES users(empID)
```

but that only creates the relationship between the tables, based on the empID columns. It doesn't create the empID column for you! You also need a line above, to define the empID column in the *leave* table, something like this:

```
create table `leave`(
lid INT NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
empID INT NOT NULL,
empname ...
... more lines ,
FOREIGN KEY(empID) REFERENCES users(empID)
```